# Downloading and Displaying pdf files from internet

Tags: c#, pdf, uwp

I have a UWP that allows me to display a pdf from a website url. It's also able to display a pdf from the project folder.
However, I am trying to display a picture placed in the local app folder with a button.
I have tried searching through google and found no workable solution. Does anyone have any suggestions to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the sample in the official documentation **Image Class**.

[Setting Image.Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image?view=winrt-22621#setting-imagesource).

[Setting Image.Source using code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image?view=winrt-22621#setting-imagesource-using-code).

Or use [FileOpenPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker?view=winrt-22621) to select a picture in a local folder.

**Page.xaml**

```
<Image x:Name="image"></Image>
<Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
    picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

    var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        IRandomAccessStream ir = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        await bi.SetSourceAsync(ir);
        image.Source = bi;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Put your image path in `Source`.

**Page.xaml**

```
<Image x:Name="image" Width="200" Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png" Visibility="Collapsed"></Image>
<Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (image.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
    {      
        image.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;        
    }
    else
    {
        image.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without opening a picker? like if I click this particular button, it automatically displays the pdf without opening a picture. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Please refer to my update, I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much. So this will only work with a .png file correct? The code will not work with a multiple page pdf file?

Comment: My code supports image formats, not just PNG. If you need to display pdf file you can use [Windows.Data.Pdf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Data.Pdf?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-22621), refer to the [PDF document sample (Windows 10)](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/PdfDocument).

Comment: Have you checked my last comment?